# Replay HTTP POST in google chrome Developer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

Im switching from firebug to Google Chrome developer tools. I like it so far, but one feature that I really missing is replaying a http post.

on firebug, I can right click on the request (on the net or console tab), "open in new tab" and replay that request. When I try the same thing on google chrome, it did not sent it as POST instead as a GET so the parameter did not sent to the server

Is there any way i can do this in chrome?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Update:**

Yes, it is possible in the latest version of Google Chrome. 
<del>Just right click on the request and select **Replay XHR**.</del>

Another way as others pointed out is to:

1. Right click request > "Copy" > "Copy ss curl". Paste it to shell. or
2. Right click request > "Copy" > "Copy as fetch". Paste it to the console tab

---

<del>There's currently no way to do this, but please star [this bug](http://crbug.com/107006) to track progress on this front.</del>

Comment: is it possible to **save** the request (e.g. as a bookmark) ?

Comment: Can be better!! If we have a option "Replay XHR in a new tab or window", like the Firebug does.

Comment: It's gone in version 45.

Comment: If you have OPTIONS enabled, you must replay the XHR from the OPTION line.  If you do it on, for instance the POST line, nothing happens.

Comment: What kind of OPTIONS do you mean? The pre-request for CORS?

Comment: What about editing the request first (like to change one parameter) and resend like Firefox has ("Edit and resend")?

Comment: are there any keyboard shortcuts to enable this?

Comment: Replay request option is not there in version 59 of Chrome as of 20 Jun 2017

Comment: Replay XHR is available in my browser, which is Chrome 60.0.3112.101

Comment: Finally found the way, thanks, .. searched a lot before.

Answer (score 27):

My favorite way is to right click on the POST request and Copy as fetch option (see attached image). I can then paste that into the console as Javascript to alter the request if needed and re-run it.

[image]

Comment: I love this option! Indeed the easiest way to update a request before running

Answer (score 14):

"Replay XHR" in Chrome only can replay, if you want to modify the post request you should use firefox and Live HTTP Headers addon.

Comment: there are addons for Chrome as well that allow you to edit headers (though maybe not at the time of writing of the answer).

Comment: as of 2021 works in regular Chrome - checked in Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 5):

As of right now (09/20/2012) this feature is available in the bleeding edge version of Chrome called [Chrome Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs). Simply right click on the xhr request in the network panel and select "Replay XHR".

It's still not quite as useful as the Firebug "open in new tab" if you are returning HTML formatted debug information.

Comment: available in Chrome Version 96.0.4664.45 (Official Build) (64-bit) - copy as fetch, change data, post - all works

Answer (score 2):

Chrome supports "Replay XHR" already, also installing a browser plugin definitely helps you if you want to modify the request. But another more flexible way is right click on the request, choose "copy -> copy as cURL", then paste the curl request to your command line terminal. Then you can modify the request however you like.

Comment: it does not anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the post request you can use Tamper Chrome (extension)

Comment: Click Replay XHR after installing Tamper Chrome and it will show a new window

Answer (score 1):

On chrome I couldn't find replay for no XHR requests, but on Firefox i found the option to resend POST requests.

[image]